# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \include

Tags: errors, biber, input-encodings

I am not sure I understand the error, but it somehow appears when I

```
\printbibliography
```

I am using biber, and don't see anything wrong with my entries..

```
@online{human_freq_range,
    author = {Julian Heuser},
    title = {Sampling},
    url = {http://recognize-speech.com/preprocessing},
    urldate = {2016-12-26},
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{
    kaldi,
    author = {Povey, Daniel and Ghoshal, Arnab and Boulianne, Gilles and Burget, Lukas and Glembek, Ondrej and Goel, Nagendra and Hannemann, Mirko and Motlicek, Petr and Qian, Yanmin and Schwarz, Petr and Silovsky, Jan and Stemmer, Georg and Vesely, Karel},
    keywords = {ASR, Automatic Speech Recognition, GMM, HTK, SGMM},
    month = dec,
    title = {The Kaldi Speech Recognition Toolkit},
    booktitle = {IEEE 2011 Workshop on Automatic Speech Recognition and Understanding},
    year = {2011},
    publisher = {IEEE Signal Processing Society},
    location = {Hilton Waikoloa Village, Big Island, Hawaii, US},
    note = {IEEE Catalog No.: CFP11SRW-USB},
}

@misc{Librosa,
    author       = {Brian McFee and
    Matt McVicar and
    Colin Raffel and
    Dawen Liang and
    Oriol Nieto and
    Eric Battenberg and
    Josh Moore and
    Dan Ellis and
    Ryuichi YAMAMOTO and
    Rachel Bittner and
    Douglas Repetto and
    Petr Viktorin and
    João Felipe Santos and
    Adrian Holovaty},
    title        = {librosa: 0.4.1},
    month        = oct,
    year         = 2015,
    doi          = {10.5281/zenodo.32193},
    url          = {https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.32193}
}

@misc{keras,
    title={Keras},
    author={Chollet, Fran\c{c}ois},
    year={2015},
    publisher={GitHub},
    howpublished={\url{https://github.com/fchollet/keras}},
}

@ARTICLE{theano,
    author = {Theano Development Team},
    title = "{Theano: A {Python} framework for fast computation of mathematical expressions}",
    journal = {arXiv e-prints},
    volume = {abs/1605.02688},
    primaryClass = "cs.SC",
    keywords = {Computer Science - Symbolic Computation, Computer Science - Learning, Computer Science - Mathematical Software},
    year = 2016,
    month = may,
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02688},
}

@misc{tensorflow,
    title={ {TensorFlow}: Large-Scale Machine Learning on Heterogeneous Systems},
    url={http://tensorflow.org/},
    note={Software available from tensorflow.org},
    author={
    Mart\'{\i}n~Abadi and
    Ashish~Agarwal and
    Paul~Barham and
    Eugene~Brevdo and
    Zhifeng~Chen and
    Craig~Citro and
    Greg~S.~Corrado and
    Andy~Davis and
    Jeffrey~Dean and
    Matthieu~Devin and
    Sanjay~Ghemawat and
    Ian~Goodfellow and
    Andrew~Harp and
    Geoffrey~Irving and
    Michael~Isard and
    Yangqing Jia and
    Rafal~Jozefowicz and
    Lukasz~Kaiser and
    Manjunath~Kudlur and
    Josh~Levenberg and
    Dan~Man\'{e} and
    Rajat~Monga and
    Sherry~Moore and
    Derek~Murray and
    Chris~Olah and
    Mike~Schuster and
    Jonathon~Shlens and
    Benoit~Steiner and
    Ilya~Sutskever and
    Kunal~Talwar and
    Paul~Tucker and
    Vincent~Vanhoucke and
    Vijay~Vasudevan and
    Fernanda~Vi\'{e}gas and
    Oriol~Vinyals and
    Pete~Warden and
    Martin~Wattenberg and
    Martin~Wicke and
    Yuan~Yu and
    Xiaoqiang~Zheng},
    year={2015},
}
```

what is wrong here?

Full error:

```
line 200: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \end
: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
line 2: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 20: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 23: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 25: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 2: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
line 8: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
: No \printglossary or \printglossaries found. (Remove \makeglossaries if you don't want any glossaries.) This document will not have a glossary.
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please always add a full MWE (Minimal Working Example) from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`.  Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: U+0301 is a combining acute character which is hard to deal with in TeX, it is better to use pre-composed characters

Comment: (but there is not a U+0301 in the code posted)

Comment: The error doesn't appear comment the the `\printbibliography` line.

Comment: please show the full error message from the log (from `!` to `?` in a `{}` code block so line breaks are preserved, that will give far more context for the error.

Comment: I've added a dropbox link to the tex file.

Comment: This has come up recently: I've closed as a dupe as the info there also applies here

Comment: I guess you were right @JosephWright